# Unicode character that modifies the next letter?

Tags: unicode

Many unicode characters modify the appearance of the previous character. is there one that
modifies the following character?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, unicode only supports modifiers after the main character.  From [definition D52 in Section 3.6, Combination  of the 6.0.0 specification](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/ch03.pdf#G30602):

> - The graphic positioning of a combining character depends on the
>     last preceding base character, unless
>     they are separated by a character that
>     is neither a combining character nor
>     either zero width joiner or zero width
>     nonjoiner. The combining character is
>     said to apply to that base character.
> - There may be no such base character, such as when a combining
>     character is at the start of text or
>     follows a control or format
>     character—for example, a carriage
>     return, tab, or right-left mark. In
>     such cases, the combining characters
>     are called isolated combining
>     characters.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought there are a few double combining characters that go between the characters to be modified (e.g. a "tie" or over-parenthesis).

Comment: @Mechanical snail - interesting, I suppose that could be considered a modification of the following character, though I suspect the rendering is still all done in reference to the preceding base character.

Comment: @jball how did you do the PDF fragment URL linking to #G30602 where it went to the exact place? All I know how to do is #page and #zoom fragments wikipedia mentioned like https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/ch03.pdf#page=25&zoom=200